# Arrange Pandas DataFrame to be used for scipy interpn

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation

I have to perform an interpolation in 3 or 4 dimensions moving from a tabular data stored as Pandas `DataFrame`.
I have the following data stored in the variable `df : DataFrame`:

```
 xm   xA   xl      z     
2.3  4.6  10.0   1.905
2.3  4.6  11.0   1.907
2.3  4.8  10.0   1.908
2.3  4.8  11.0   1.909
2.4  4.6  10.0   1.811
2.4  4.6  11.0   1.812
2.4  4.8  10.0   1.813
2.4  4.8  11.0   1.814
```

`xm, xa, xl` are the axis from which the grid should be drawn. The column `z` contains the values from which the interpolation is to be performed. Indeed, the regular grid I came up with is calculated as:

```
grid = np.meshgrid(*(df.xm,df.xA,df.xl))
```

Now my problem is how to turn the Z-series data from the DataFrame into a np.array to be passed to the Scipy function:

```
from scipy import interpolate
p0 = (xm0,xA0,xl0)
z0 = interpolate.interpn(grid, myarray, p0)
```

Comment: `grid = np.meshgrid(*(df.xm,df.xA,df.xl))` ? Isn't same as `grid = np.meshgrid(df.xm,df.xA,df.xl)`

Comment: I think you can use something like `df.z.values.reshape(grid[0].shape)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SCKU for the hint on the z-column reshape. I was using

```
grid = np.meshgrid(*(df.xm,df.xA,df.xl))
```

following the example from [scipy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html).
It was actually enough to pass the tuple of base axis array:

```
grid = np.meshgrid(xm,xA,xLn)
z = df.z.values.reshape(grid[0].shape)
xt = (df.xM,df.xA,df.xLn)
p0 = (xM0,xA0,xLn0)
val = interpolate.interpn(xt, z, p0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, from the scipy doc link, I think they use `points = (x, y, z)` and `np.meshgrid(*points)` to improve readability (math).